# Shopify form file upload

Tags: file, input, shopify, liquid

I have this liquid on a page template:

```
{% form 'contact' %}

{% if form.posted_successfully? %}
    <p class="note success">Success!</p>
{% endif %}

{{ form.errors | default_errors }}

<p>
    <label for="ContactFormName">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="ContactFormName" name="contact[name]" value="{% if form[name_attr] %}{{ form[name_attr] }}{% elsif customer %}{{ customer.name }}{% endif %}" required>
</p>

<p>
    <label for="ContactFormCV">Upload CV</label>
    <input type="file" id="ContactFormCV" name="contact[cv]" required />
</p>

{% endform %}
```

The problem is that when a file is selected for upload and the form submitted, the email that is received only shows the file name. Ideally it should have the file attached, or a link to the file.

If I change the form tag to this...

```
{% form 'contact', enctype: 'multipart/form-data' %}
```

...I get this error when submitting a form:

```
There was a problem loading this website
Try refreshing the page.
If the site still doesn't load, please try again in a few minutes.
```

How can I get this to work?

Note: This form is being used on a custom template in the **templates** directory (page.employment.liquid).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Shopify liquid forms do not accept file input type.

You have basically two solutions:

- Use an external app
- Code an Ajax request to upload file to an external server via a PHP file as explained [here](https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-design/adding-lt-input-type-quot-file-quot-gt-to-contact-form/m-p/798714/highlight/true#M200793) (keeping in mind that there is a huge work to do to sanitize and secure upload process on your server)

HTH

Comment: AJAX call may not work directly into Shopify theme, it gives your CORS errors, for this need to create a custom app and add a proxy to make an AJAX call.

Comment: @Onkar As the request is sent to external server it will depend on this server's config ;). But, anyway, as explained, not a really good option to me.